# nagios check http with form authentication

Tags: authentication, nagios

Several of the websites that require nagios (or icinga) monitoring have form based authentication. Is there a check_ script available that does form based authentication for nagios (or icinga).

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure. the check_http plugin using the -P option allows you to post data. See all the options here: http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_http